# converting string list of fractions into float from scraped html / cleanest method

Tags: python, html, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, python-3.4

Trying to convert this scraped string list of odds fractions into a list of float decimals in the same format for use in calculations.

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

url = requests.get('http://www.oddschecker.com/tennis/match-coupon')
html = url.content
soup = BeautifulSoup(html)

for row in soup.find_all("tr", {"data-market-id": True}):
    participants = [item.get_text(strip=True) for item in row.find_all('span', class_='fixtures-bet-name')]
    odds = [item.get_text(strip=True) for item in row.find_all('span', class_='odds')]

    print (participants[0], odds[0], participants[1], odds[1])
```

Comment: Correct me if I'm wrong - if the value is `8/15`, for example, you want to evaluate it and output `0.53`? Thanks.

Comment: @alexe you are correct

Comment: @alecxe your previous solution was so close

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
def convert(item):
    ls = list(map(int, item.strip('()').split('/')))
    l = len(ls)
    if l == 1:
        return ls[0]
    elif l == 2:
        a, b = ls
        return float(a) / b if b else 0
    raise RuntimeError('More than 2 values!')
```

Then call:

```
odds = [convert(item.get_text(strip=True)) for item in row.find_all('span', class_='odds')]
```

Comment: when implemented that returns 'Constanza Vega <map object at 0x1066fb940> Nadia Podoroska <map object at 0x1066fb9e8>' which is only 1 match, not the entire table.

Comment: @TwiggyGarcia sorry there was a typo, edited. could you please check again?

Comment: when i try and integrate it gives me "ValueError: need more than 1 value to unpack"

Comment: @TwiggyGarcia Then, there are values that don't conform to the structure we expect. For example, when splitted, it's expected to be two values but may not be there. Let me make function more robust.

Comment: Traceback (most recent call last):
  line 22, in <module>
    odds = [convert(item.get_text(strip=True)) for item in row.find_all('span', class_='odds')]
  ", line 22, in <listcomp>
    odds = [convert(item.get_text(strip=True)) for item in row.find_all('span', class_='odds')]
  File ", line 13, in convert
    l = len(ls)
TypeError: object of type 'map' has no len()

Comment: @TwiggyGarcia last change for py3 since map returns iterator instead of list in py3. Wrapped map via list to convert it into a list.

Comment: this edit gives me a float decimal value for only 1 match 'Constanza Vega 3 Nadia Podoroska 0.2222222222222222' i still can't return the original list with decimals as a float

Comment: @TwiggyGarcia original is `['(3)', '(2/9)']` so what's the problem.

Comment: i have edited my code - this video will show you what i'm talking about - http://we.tl/N3mYZo0UGy

Comment: @TwiggyGarcia hadn't seen the video, no problem. Result is good to hear!